# Figuring out the character value in finding first non repeated character in a string

Tags: java, hashmap

I am working on finding first non repeating character in a String which is as follows:

```
package com.tk.practice;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FirstNonRepeatedCharacter {

public static void main(String[] args) {


        String str = "stress";

        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();

        int length = ch.length;
        //System.out.println(length);
        for(int i = 0; i<length;i++){
                char character = str.charAt(i); 
                Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
                if(map.containsKey(character)){
                    map.put(character, map.get(character)+1);
                }
                else{
                    map.put(character, 1);
                }

                for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> m : map.entrySet()){
                            //Integer ill = m.getValue();
                            //Character ch1 = m.getKey();
                            //if(ill == 1){

                                System.out.println("Key: "+m.getKey()+" Value: "+m.getValue());

                            //}


       }




}

}}
```

It's just printing value one for each character right now. But I am trying to understand one thing in the following line:

```
if(map.containsKey(character)){
                        map.put(character, map.get(character)+1);
                    }
```

Since, the `value` is an integer value, then why `map.get(character)` isn't throwing any error as `map.get(character)` should be retrieving the character, right and not the value? I was thinking of using `getKey()` but that throws error. Please explain me if I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map.get` returns an `Integer` since that's what the values in your map are. `getKey` will return a `Character` and `get` will return an `Integer` since the keys in your map are characters and the values are integers. `get` gives you the value at the key you provide.